# Django object filter - highest bid for every item

Tags: python, django, filter, model

I want to filter an object which contains the highest price for each listing_id.

from models.py

```
class Listing(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Bid(models.Model):
   listing_id = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="listing")
   user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user")
   price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2, blank=False, validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
```

Can I get some advice guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can annotate the `Listing` model with the highest bid:

```
from django.db.models import Max

Listing.objects.annotate(
    highest_bid=Max('listing__price')
)
```

Or if you want the `Bid` objects, you can first annotate with the largest bid of its listing, and then filter on the price:

```
from django.db.models import F, Max

Bid.objects.annotate(
    highest_bid=Max('listing_id__listing__price')
).filter(
    price=F('highest_bid')
)
```

Comment: Thank you, for others who will read this: "..filter(price=F('highest'))"